# unexpected token `done' in while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to know what is the syntax error in this bash srcipt

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=1594184400
while true do
  NEXT=$((CURRENT+300))
  CURRENT=$NEXT
done
```

That I get

```
syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

error?

Comment: If you are new to shell scripting, I would recommend [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net), which is also available as standalone tool in many Linux distributions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either need  a semicolon after `true` on the second line or to put `do` on the following line by itself.

Either this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=1594184400
while true; do     
  NEXT=$((CURRENT+300))
  CURRENT=$NEXT
done
```

Or this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=1594184400
while true 
do
  NEXT=$((CURRENT+300))
  CURRENT=$NEXT
done
```

You can check shell scripts for errors here:

https://www.shellcheck.net/

You can also run `bash -n script` on the terminal to check for errors.

Comment: Just to add *why* this is necessary, otherwise `do` is simply parsed as an argument to `true`, and the parser is still looking for the required keyword `do` in a command position when it encounters `done`.